# msdeploy command renames content file name if it has special characters

Tags: c#, packaging, msdeploy

I am using command

> "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync
>   -source:manifest="C:\PackageInfo\SourceManifest.xml" -dest:package="C:\Output\Lifecare.LIS.OnlineHelp.Chemistry.zip" -declareParamFile:"C:\PackageInfo\Parameters.xml" > WebDeployPackage.log

to package my .htm files

This works fine when file name is in English, but in case of Swedish language it renames special charaters like" Ö ", this character has 2 dot on top of 'O' so it converts this charter to "+¦"

For example my source folder has file name 'arbetsflöde.htm' then in package folder it renames this file name to 'arbetsfl+¦de'

Can anyone help me to find how to stop it from renaming files?

Answer (score 0):

We decided to keep file name in English.